# canvas or OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas

I am embarking on a project (game) and I have a question about the implementation, will be developed specifically for Android and want to know which is better (easier, faster to develop and portable). canvas or OpenGL ES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you already have a good working knowledge of OpenGL, then using a Canvas will be easier and faster.  In terms of portability it really isn't as clear cut.

That said you should probably consider using one the pre-existing game engines, if you really only about Android then you should check out http://www.andengine.org/ its a great engine with a strong community and lots of great little example games.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm not really sure where I read this,but when it's about developing game if you have any knowledge of `OpenGL`, you better use that,because the system is separating more space for your application so it can run without lagging or crash.So you can't get an `Memory Full` error. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)